# UIAccelerometer unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Does anyone get
-[UIAccelerometer bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a23f0

I do init the accelerometer:

```
UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/30.0f;
accel.delegate = self;
```

The reason I am asking is that on some devices the app works, and on others just crashes. And I am not sure what is the reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds as if you send the accelerometer a `bytes` message, which it doesn't implement. The code you show doesn't have a problem, maybe do search for `bytes` and double-check that usage.

Comment: Thanks Eiko, I check that myself, but no [xxx bytes] message is sent.